# Guarantee exact data width in (void*) array in C

Tags: c, arrays, types

I have a simple function in C which provides a `void*` pointer to a data array. I know the size (in bytes) of each individual data-point within this memory block, and need to guarantee that I can modify each data-point in this block without accidentally altering neighboring data-points. In this example, I want to decrement each value by 1.

All data points are either 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit.

eg:

```
void myFunction(void* data, size_t arraySize, size_t widthPerDataPoint)
{
  if(!data)
    return -1;
  size_t w = widthPerDataPoint;
  int numPoints = arraySize / widthPerDataPoint;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<numPoints; i++)
  {
    if(w==1)       // 8 bit
      (*((int8_t*)data + i))--;
    else if(w==2)  // 16 bit
      (*((int16_t*)data + i))--;
    else if(w==4)  // 32 bit
      (*((int32_t*)data + i))--;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the int8_t, etc, datatypes only guarantee their minimum size, according to C99 specifications, and not an **exact** size. Is there any way to re-cast and modify the data in-place and guarantee I won't smash my array or touch neighboring data points? Also, is there an equivalent technique that would somehow work for other data widths (ie: 24-bit, 60-bit, etc)?

Comment: Why you don't use structs ? linked lists using structs ?

Comment: Certain API's in C use (void*) to pass in generic data, and leave it to the calling application to determine the format of the data with other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int8_t` is guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits, and if `CHAR_BIT==1`, exactly 1 byte.

Quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the latest C standard, section 7.20.1.1:

> The typedef name **int***N***_t** designates a signed integer type
>   with width *N*, no padding bits, and a two’s complement
>   representation. Thus, **int8_t** denotes such a signed integer type
>   with a width of exactly 8 bits.

Though for your purposes it might make more sense to use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, et al.

If the implementation doesn't support types with the required characteristics, it won't define them; you can detect this by checking, for example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef UINT8_MAX
/* uint8_t exists */
#else
/* uint8_t doesn't exist */
#endif
```

(If `CHAR_BIT != 8`, then neither `int8_t` nor `uint8_t` will be defined.)

It's the `[u]intleast_N_t` and `[u]intfast_t` types for which the standard only guarantees minimum sizes.

You'll have to guarantee that both the array and the offsets within it are properly aligned for the types you're using to access it. I presume you're already taking care of that.

Comment: Even though `int8_t` is guaranteed to be exactly 8 bits, there's no guarantee that a compiler won't emit a read/modify/write cycle on a larger word that contains an `int8_t` object.  Indeed I believe that the Alpha platform requires this.

Comment: @caf: True, and worth pointing out, but I don't see any indication that this would be a problem for the OP.

Comment: I suspect I may have been reading more into the question than was really there.

Comment: I can guarantee the data provided is properly aligned. This still doesn't help in my case though, as it doesn't address the case of 16-bit and 32-bit numbers.

Comment: @Dogbert: Perhaps I'm missing something. The C standard guarantees that `int16_t` and `uint16_t` are exactly 16 bits, and that `int32_t` and `uint32_t` are exactly 32 bits. N1570 7.20.1.1 is titled "Exact-width integer types". The only real potential problem is if `CHAR_BIT !+ 8`, but that's rare (practically nonexistent for hosted implementations), and easy to check for with an `assert`.

Comment: I think I may have been initially looking at outdated documentation. I thought that according to C99, `int16_t`, for example, only guaranteed a signed (twos-complement) integer at least 16-bits in width, not exactly 16-bits. Thank you.

Comment: @Dogbert: I've seen a whole lot of C documentation, and I don't recall any that didn't guarantee the exact width of `intN_t`. Could you have been looking at `intfast16_t` or `intleast16_t` instead? Also, `int` is only guaranteed to be at least 16 bits wide. Anyway, I'm glad you solved your problem. The latest C99 draft is [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

By definition, incrementing a pointer of type `T*` by *n* will shift it by `n * sizeof(T)` bytes. Therefore, consistency is guaranteed to you by the compiler. No worries.

Comment: If `int8_t` could be bigger than 8 bits, that wouldn't help; `sizeof (int8_t)` could vary from one implementation to another. But in fact, the OP's assumption is incorrect; see my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson, but that's exactly the point. Whatever the size in his specific implementation, memory access will be consistent with the underlying layout.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't seem entirely unreasonable. I personally would probably do something like this:

```
 switch(widthPerDataPoint)
 {
    case 1:
       {
          int8_t *dptr = data;
          for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
             dptr[i]--;
       }
       break;
    case 2:
       {
          int16_t *dptr = data;
          for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
             dptr[i]--;
       }
       break;

    case 4:
       {
          int32_t *dptr = data;
          for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
             dptr[i]--;
       }
       break;

    default:
       fprintf(stderr, "Someone gave the wrong width - width=%d\n", 
               widthPerDatapoint);
       break;
}
```

The advantage here is that you don't get a bunch of conditions in every loop. The compiler MAY sort it out anyways, but I don't always trust compilers to figure such things out - and I think it's a bit cleaner too.

Answer (score -1):

How about the following?

1. Copy the value out to a local int of whatever size
2. Perform the decrement on the local variable
3. Use an appropriate bit mask to zero out the location in the array
   (e.g., ~0xFF for 8-bit)
4. 'And' the local variable back into the array.